# Set background of the PDF

Tags: pdf-generation

I generated an PDF from PHP TCPDF. Is it possible to set the background color outside of the generated PDF?[image]

By default its gray. I would like it to be black.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see you're using the PDF Viewer on Chrome right? 
After searches, I think it's not possible to change the background of the pdf viewer (maybe with chrome extensions?) because the background is not part of the PDF himself.

The only solution that I find which can maybe change the background was to change the PDF Viewer (there is an example with Google Reader to Acrobat : [Change PDF Viewer on Chrome](http://blogs.adobe.com/vikrant/2010/12/use-adobe-plugins-to-view-pdfs-inside-google-chrome/).)